# Dual Boot, win 11 won't boot without win 10 drive connected

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, windows-11, dualboot

PLease help, cause I am running out of ideas.

I have a win 11 system drive(NVMe) and an empty win 10 drive(SSD) which was formerly a system drive (so it has efi partition etc.).

Now, when I detach the win 10 drive I can't boot my win 11.
I've tried startup repair, changing UEFI to CMS in Bios, fixing it via cmd and nothing works.
To startup my main win11 system I have to have the old win 10 system drive connected.
I would really like to avoid formatting everything- any ideas?

Comment: Create a new EFI partition on your new system disk.

Comment: @Ramhound I did that but it still won't work- I have to have old win 10 drive connected.

Comment: An empty ESP does nothing. You need to copy the contents of the old to the new one. Unless you want to keep the old drive in which case don't touch the old ESP, format the rest, that's all.